# Bug with strtotime()

Tags: php, web-scraping, screen-scraping

The Simple HTML DOM library is used to extract the timestamp from a webpage. `strtotime` is then used to convert the extracted timestamp to a MySQL timestamp.

**Problem:** When `strtotime()` is usede on a valid timestamp, `NULL` is returned (See `2:`). However when Simple HTML DOM is not used in the 2nd example, everything works properly.

What is happening, and how can this be fixed??

**Output:**

```
1:2013-03-03, 12:06PM
2:
3:1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

**var_dump($time)**

```
string(25) "2013-03-03, 12:06PM"
```

**PHP**

```
include_once(path('app') . 'libraries/simple_html_dom.php');

// Convert to HTML DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html_raw = '<p class="postinginfo">Posted: <date>2013-03-03, 12:06PM EST</date></p>';
$html->load($html_raw);

// Extract timestamp
$time = $html->find('.postinginfo', 0);
$pattern = '/Posted: (.*?) (.).T/s';
$matches = '';
preg_match($pattern, $time, $matches);
$time = $matches[1];

echo '1:' . $time . '<br>';
echo '2:' . strtotime($time) . '<br>';
echo '3:' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($time));
```

---

### 2nd Example

**PHP (Working, without Simple HTML DOM)**

```
// Extract posting timestamp
$time = 'Posted: 2013-03-03, 12:06PM EST';
$pattern = '/Posted: (.*?) (.).T/s';
$matches = '';
preg_match($pattern, $time, $matches);
$time = $matches[1];

echo '1:' . $time . '<br>';
echo '2:' . strtotime($time) . '<br>';
echo '3:' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($time));
```

**Output (Correct)**

```
1:2013-03-03, 12:06PM
2:1362312360
3:2013-03-03 12:06:00
```

**var_dump($time)**

```
string(19) "2013-03-03, 12:06PM"
```

Comment: Can you add simple_html_dom.php code?

Comment: @MIIB Sure: http://pastebin.com/DxhmsRC1

Comment: There's little to no chance it's related, are you 100% *sure* your inputs are the same?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes, I copied the timestamp `2013-03-03, 12:06PM EST` from 1st example into 2nd example

Comment: use var_dump instead of echo to check for hidden characters

Comment: Cast explicitly to string?

Comment: var_dump results are different, updated original post. Why is var_dump reporting a different number of characters between the 2 `$time` variables? They look the same

Comment: Are you viewing in a browser? Try to view the source - it might be rendering html tags

Comment: It says `string(25)` but I see only 19 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `var_dump()`, the `$time` string you extracted from the HTML code is **25** characters long.

The string you *see*, `"2013-03-03, 12:06PM"`, is only **19** characters long.

So, where are those 6 extra characters?  Well, it's pretty obvious, really: the string you're trying to parse is really `"<date>2013-03-03, 12:06PM"`.  But when you print it into an HTML document, that `<date>` is parsed as an HTML tag by the browser.

To see it, use the "View Source" function in your browser.  Or, *much* better yet, use `htmlspecialchars()` when printing any variables that are not *supposed* to contain HTML code.